# SharpSVN doesn't update files

Tags: svn, sharpsvn, svn-update

```
                    SvnUpdateArgs asdf = new SvnUpdateArgs();
                    asdf.AllowObstructions = false;
                    asdf.Depth = SvnDepth.Infinity;
                    asdf.IgnoreExternals = false;
                    asdf.UpdateParents = true;
                    asdf.Revision = SvnRevision.Head;
                    asdf.Conflict += new EventHandler<SvnConflictEventArgs>(asdf_Conflict);

                    asdf.Notify += new EventHandler<SvnNotifyEventArgs>(asdf_Notify);
                    asdf.Progress += new EventHandler<SvnProgressEventArgs>(asdf_Progress);


                    SvnUpdateResult res;

                    client.Status(dir, new EventHandler<SvnStatusEventArgs>(Status_Hook));



                    if (client.Update(dir, asdf, out res))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Updated");
                        Console.WriteLine(res.Revision);
                        Console.WriteLine(res.ResultMap);
                    }

    static void asdf_Conflict(object sender, SvnConflictEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Choice = SvnAccept.TheirsFull;
    }
```

so i see **Updated** written, but existing files aren't updated.
if some files missing - they will be downloaded.
but existing files doesn't updated.

i m going mad with that stuff, please help me, my hero!

Comment: What version of SharpSvn do you use? I've tried with `1.8-x86` and it seems to be working.

Comment: @johny seems like 1.8004.2609.15378 but for x64

Comment: @johny of course no result, problem NOT solved, seems like the logic still lives on this planet. current version: SharpSvn 1.8005.2698.

Comment: Is file(s) modified before you try to update? Does `dir` point on 'clean' working copy?

Comment: working copy revision number and remote copy revision number will help to figure problem out

Comment: @mayer06 can't do that coz my lead
but thanks, you chereed my today up C:

Comment: Are you checking `res` to see what results were returned by the update attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the MergedFile property. If not, SharpSVN won't be merging the file as you described.

```
static void asdf_Conflict(object sender, SvnConflictEventArgs e)
{
    e.Choice = SvnAccept.TheirsFull;
    e.MergedFile = e.TheirFile;
}
```